# Questions before installing Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux

Is there an installation GUI for Arch Linux, installing the current Arch Linux Distribution correctly? Is there a big Arch Linux community, which I can get help from? What should I be aware of before installing Arch Linux, as a Debian/Linux Mint user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only supported method for installing Arch Linux is the command line tools outlined in the official documentation: the [Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide). There is also the community provided [Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide), which has more detail for those unfamiliar with Arch.

The Arch community is much smaller than many of the other, larger and more popular distributions (like Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, *et al*), but Arch is not aiming for a large user base. As the [about page of the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux) explains:

> Whereas many GNU/Linux distributions attempt to be more user-friendly,
>   Arch Linux has always been, and shall always remain user-centric. The
>   distribution is intended to fill the needs of those contributing to
>   it, rather than trying to appeal to as many users as possible. It is
>   targeted at the proficient GNU/Linux user, or anyone with a
>   do-it-yourself attitude who is willing to read the documentation, and
>   solve their own problems.

If you are coming from one of the more popular distributions, you should be aware that Arch is a "do it yourself" distribution. There are no preconfigured desktop environments, window managers, etc: *everything* requires you to make your own choices and set them up the way you see fit.

The community on the forums, IRC and mailing lists will provide knowledgeable support, but they expect that you will know how to [ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and be familiar enough with the system you have installed to contribute to solving your issue. Hand holding and [help vampirism](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) is actively discouraged.

Arch users are also expected to [contribute to the distribution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getting_involved); either through maintaining packages in [the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/) (Arch User Repository), assisting with documentation, bug reports, or just helping other users in the support channels.